# Magento custom module adds HTML block to header

Tags: php, magento

I'm creating a custom module for Magento and the cleanest way I found to add HTML code to the header is to create my own Block in the module and then add PHP code to render that block in template header.phtml.

I'm just wondering is there any way to be less intruding by having all my codes just in my module folder?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<reference name="header">
    <block type="your_module/yourblockclass" name="yourblockname" template="your_module/yourtemplate.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

Add the code above to the default-layout-handle in your custom `layout.xml` file.
Fetch the block via

`$this->getChildHtml('yourblockname')`

from within the `header.phtml` file.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to modify the header.phtml template file just add `output="toHtml"` to your block declaration, like this:

```
<reference name="header">
   <block type="your_module/yourblockclass" name="yourblockname" template="your_module/yourtemplate.phtml" output="toHtml"/>
</reference>
```